Отображение тулбара в приложении
В приложении есть тулбар, в нем несколько иконок
по нажатию одной из них должно появляться меню поиска по WebView
Но почему то, когда я добавляю код тулбара, в котором должен появляться поиск, все иконки меню пропадают.
Вот код элементов тулбара
// Создаем LinearLayout для поисковых элементов
        searchLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        searchLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        searchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Создаем поле для ввода искомого текста
        searchInput = new EditText(this);
        searchInput.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

        // Создаем кнопку "Поиск"
        searchButton = new Button(this);
        searchButton.setText("Поиск");
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String query = searchInput.getText().toString();
                myWebView.findAllAsync(query);
            }
        });

        // Создаем кнопку "Назад"
        backButton = new Button(this);
        backButton.setText("Назад");
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myWebView.findNext(false);
            }
        });

        // Добавляем элементы поиска в searchLayout
        searchLayout.addView(searchInput);
        searchLayout.addView(searchButton);
        searchLayout.addView(backButton);

        // Добавляем WebView и searchLayout в основной макет
        mainLayout.addView(searchLayout);

        setContentView(mainLayout);

        // Настраиваем Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar(this);
        toolbar.setTitle("WebView Search");
        mainLayout.addView(toolbar, 0);
        setActionBar(toolbar);

Вот так я отрабатываю нажатие на иконку поиска:
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search:
                if (item.getItemId() == 1) {
                    if (isSearchVisible) {
                        searchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        searchLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    isSearchVisible = !isSearchVisible;
                    return true;
                }

Что я сделал не так?
Если убрать этот код, то иконки в тулбаре отображаются, но при нажатии на поиск, конечно, ничего не происходит:
   // Настраиваем Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar(this);
        toolbar.setTitle("WebView Search");
        mainLayout.addView(toolbar, 0);
        setActionBar(toolbar); 


Нашел решение
Нужно было просто использовать androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar; вместо androidx.widget.Toolbar;
